# Text in table cell in PyQt6 not showing on first insert

Tags: python, pyqt6

## Conditions

There is a table [`sputnik_table`](https://github.com/polnikov/air-system/blob/c31e06e3ee2aecbe33fde47258a7a6e905024892/app.py#L249). When entered in cell 1, cell 2 should display the calculated value. Handler function [`calculate_klapan_pressure_loss`](https://github.com/polnikov/air-system/blob/c31e06e3ee2aecbe33fde47258a7a6e905024892/app.py#L618).

**sputnik_table**

```
def create_sputnik_table_box(self) -> object:
        _box = QGroupBox(CONSTANTS.SPUTNIK_TABLE.TITLE)
        style = self.box_style
        _box.setStyleSheet(style)
        _box.setFixedHeight(298)

        _layout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.sputnik_table = QTableWidget(5, 15)
        _table = self.sputnik_table
        _table.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
        _table.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
        _table.horizontalHeader().setStyleSheet("QHeaderView::section { background-color: #F3F3F3 }")
        _table.setStyleSheet("QTableWidget { border: 2px solid grey; }")
        _table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(CONSTANTS.SPUTNIK_TABLE.HEADER)
        _table.setObjectName(CONSTANTS.SPUTNIK_TABLE.NAME)

        num_rows = _table.rowCount()
        num_cols = _table.columnCount()

        # устанавливаем виджет QTableWidgetItem для всех ячеек таблицы и отключаем редактирование
        for row in range(num_rows):
            for col in range(num_cols):
                _table.setItem(row, col, QTableWidgetItem())
                _table.item(row, col).setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)
                editable = (
                    (0, 1),
                    (1, 1),
                    (1, 2),
                    (1, 3),
                    (1, 4),
                    (1, 11),
                    (3, 1),
                    (3, 2),
                    (3, 3),
                    (3, 4),
                    (3, 11),
                )
                if (row, col) not in editable:
                    _table.item(row, col).setFlags(Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsEnabled)
                else:
                    _table.item(row, col).setBackground(QColor(229, 255, 204))

        for row in range(num_rows):
            _table.setRowHeight(row, 36)
            match row:
                case 2 | 4:
                    _table.setSpan(row, 0, 1, 13)
                case 0:
                    _table.setSpan(row, 2, 1, 11)
                case 1 | 3:
                    _table.setSpan(row, 14, 2, 1)

        for col in range(num_cols):
            match col:
                case 0:
                    _table.setColumnWidth(col, 80)
                case 1:
                    _table.setColumnWidth(col, 80)
                case 3 | 4:
                    _table.setColumnWidth(col, 110)
                case _:
                    _table.setColumnWidth(col, 72)

        # установка заливки для редактируемых столбцов
        _table.item(0, 1).setBackground(QColor(229, 255, 204))

        # заполняем таблицу
        _table.item(0, 0).setText(CONSTANTS.SPUTNIK_TABLE.KLAPAN_LABEL)
        _table.item(0, 1).setToolTip(CONSTANTS.SPUTNIK_TABLE.KLAPAN_FLOW_TOOLTIP)
        _table.item(1, 0).setText(CONSTANTS.SPUTNIK_TABLE.SECTOR_1)
        _table.item(3, 0).setText(CONSTANTS.SPUTNIK_TABLE.SECTOR_2)

        # размещаем радиокнопки
        for row in (1, 3):
            widget = QWidget()
            layout = QHBoxLayout(widget)
            layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)
            radio_button = QRadioButton(widget)
            layout.addWidget(radio_button)
            widget.setLayout(layout)
            _table.setCellWidget(row, 14, widget)

        self.radio_button1 = _table.cellWidget(1, 14).findChild(QRadioButton)
        self.radio_button2 = _table.cellWidget(3, 14).findChild(QRadioButton)
        radio_button1, radio_button2 = self.radio_button1, self.radio_button2
        radio_button1.setChecked(True)

        radio_button1.setToolTip(CONSTANTS.SPUTNIK_TABLE.RADIO_TOOLTIP_1)
        radio_button2.setToolTip(CONSTANTS.SPUTNIK_TABLE.RADIO_TOOLTIP_2)

        # обработчики
        radio_button1.clicked.connect(self.set_sputnik_airflow_in_main_table_by_radiobutton_1)
        radio_button2.clicked.connect(self.set_sputnik_airflow_in_main_table_by_radiobutton_2)

        radio_button2.clicked.connect(self.uncheck_radio_button_1)
        radio_button1.clicked.connect(self.uncheck_radio_button_2)

        radio_button1.clicked.connect(self.calculate_kms_by_radiobutton_1)
        radio_button2.clicked.connect(self.calculate_kms_by_radiobutton_2)
        radio_button1.clicked.connect(self.calculate_branch_pressure_by_radiobutton_1)
        radio_button2.clicked.connect(self.calculate_branch_pressure_by_radiobutton_2)
        radio_button1.clicked.connect(self.calculate_full_pressure_by_radiobutton_1)
        radio_button2.clicked.connect(self.calculate_full_pressure_by_radiobutton_2)

        _table.cellChanged.connect(self.set_sputnik_airflow_in_main_table)
        _table.cellChanged.connect(self.set_deflector_pressure_in_main_table)

        _table.cellChanged.connect(self.calculate_klapan_pressure_loss)
        _table.cellChanged.connect(self.calculate_air_velocity)
        _table.cellChanged.connect(self.calculate_diameter)
        _table.cellChanged.connect(self.calculate_dynamic)
        _table.cellChanged.connect(self.calculate_specific_pressure_loss)
        _table.cellChanged.connect(self.calculate_m)
        _table.cellChanged.connect(self.calculate_linear_pressure_loss)
        _table.cellChanged.connect(self.calculate_local_pressure_loss)
        _table.cellChanged.connect(self.calculate_sputnik_full_pressure_loss)
        _table.cellChanged.connect(self.calculate_kms)
        _table.cellChanged.connect(self.calculate_result_sputnik_pressure)
        _table.cellChanged.connect(self.calculate_branch_pressure)
        _table.cellChanged.connect(self.calculate_full_pressure)

        _table.itemChanged.connect(self.validate_input_data_in_tables)

        _layout.addWidget(_table)
        _box.setLayout(_layout)
        return _box
```

**calculate_klapan_pressure_loss**

```
def calculate_klapan_pressure_loss(self, row=False, column=False) -> None:
        sender = self.sender()
        if isinstance(sender, QComboBox):
            klapan_widget_value = CONSTANTS.INIT_DATA.KLAPAN_ITEMS.get(row)
            hand_klapan_flow = self.klapan_input.text()
            current_klapan_flow = self.sputnik_table.item(0, 1).text()
            self._calculate_klapan_pressure_loss(klapan_widget_value, hand_klapan_flow, current_klapan_flow)

        elif isinstance(sender, QLineEdit):
            klapan_widget_value = CONSTANTS.INIT_DATA.KLAPAN_ITEMS.get(self.klapan_widget.currentText())
            hand_klapan_flow = row
            current_klapan_flow = self.sputnik_table.item(0, 1).text()
            self._calculate_klapan_pressure_loss(klapan_widget_value, hand_klapan_flow, current_klapan_flow)

        elif isinstance(sender, QTableWidget):
            if row == 0 and column == 1:
                klapan_widget_value = CONSTANTS.INIT_DATA.KLAPAN_ITEMS.get(self.klapan_widget.currentText())
                hand_klapan_flow = self.klapan_input.text()
                current_klapan_flow = self.sputnik_table.item(0, 1).text()
                self._calculate_klapan_pressure_loss(klapan_widget_value, hand_klapan_flow, current_klapan_flow)


    def _calculate_klapan_pressure_loss(self, klapan_widget_value, hand_klapan_flow, current_klapan_flow) -> None:
        table = self.sputnik_table
        if hand_klapan_flow or klapan_widget_value == '--':
            klapan_flow = hand_klapan_flow
        else:
            klapan_flow = klapan_widget_value

        if all([current_klapan_flow, klapan_flow]):
            current_klapan_flow = int(current_klapan_flow)
            klapan_flow = int(klapan_flow)
            pressure_loss = 10 * pow(current_klapan_flow / klapan_flow, 2)
            pressure_loss = "{:.2f}".format(round(pressure_loss, 2))
            table.item(0, 13).setText(pressure_loss)
            table.item(0, 13).setBackground(QColor(153, 255, 255))
        else:
            table.item(0, 13).setText('')
            table.item(0, 13).setBackground(QColor(255, 255, 255))
```

table picture:
[image: table picture]

[**Full project file**](https://github.com/polnikov/air-system/blob/main/app.py)

## Problem

After starting the program, if you enter any number in cell 1, cell 2 is processed by the function, but does not display text (color fill is applied). Then, if you enter a number again, but different from the original one, then the text appears in the cell and all subsequent entries in cell 1 are processed as needed.

**This behavior happened "suddenly"**

1. If you change the cell in the handler function, for example, to the next one (on the left), then the text is inserted from the first time.
2. If you set the text in this cell when creating a table, it is also displayed immediately without problems.

Comment: Sorry but questions should be self-contained, not relying on external resources. Please [edit] your question and provide a valid [mre] (it *must* be *both* minimal *and* reproducible).